# SortVisuals in Powerbi Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a powerbi report with some visuals in the report.I want to sort visual.How can i do that? I also want to sort the report based on the columns and increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort the visual follow the below steps.

1.Get the pages from the report

```
 const pages = await report.getPages();
```

2.Get the active page from the report

```
const activePage = pages.find(function (page) 
                    { return page.isActive })[0];
```

3.Get the visuals from the active page

```
const visuals = await activePage.getVisuals();
```

4.Select the visual you want to sort

```
var visual = visuals.find(function(visual) 
             { return visual.name === "VisualContainer1" })[0];
```

5.Declare a variable and set the fields .In the direction you can specify Ascending.

```
const request = {
    orderBy: {
        table: "SalesFact",
        measure: "Total Category Volume"
    },
    direction: models.SortDirection.Descending
};
```

6.Use `sortBy` and it will sort your visuals

```
await visual.sortBy(request);
```

To sort visual by column, replace `measure` with `column` and add the column.

References
[sort-visuals-by](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/sort-visuals-by)